# How to fix error 70 from parsing odds from site?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy odds for 1x2, both teams to score, and over/under 2.5 from oddsportal. And I only want odds from league that I choose. But after 40 minutes of executing the code, show me the `error 70 : permission denied`. What is wrong in my code? (It showed me 300 games but there were more for that day)

```
Sub test()

    Dim IE() As Object
    Dim IE1 As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim link1x2 As String
    Dim linkover As String
    Dim linkbtts As String

    ''Novo código
    Set IE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE1.Visible = False
    IE1.Navigate "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20190420"

    Do While IE1.Busy Or IE1.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE1.Document
    Set jogos = doc.getElementsByClassName("deactivate")
    ReDim IE(0 To jogos.Length * 3)
    i = 2
    j = 0
    For Each jogo In jogos
        URL = jogo.Children(1).Children(0).href

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Set IE(j) = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        link1x2 = URL & "#1X2;2"
        IE(j).Visible = False
        IE(j).Navigate link1x2

        Do While IE(j).Busy Or IE(j).ReadyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Set doc = IE(j).Document
        Set equipas = doc.getElementById("col-content").Children(0)
        Set liga = doc.getElementsByClassName("home")(0).Children(0).Children(3)


        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        For k = 1 To 25
            If liga.innerText = Worksheets("Plan2").Range("A" & k) Then
                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("M" & i) = liga.innerText
                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("A" & i) = equipas.innerText
                oddH = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(1).innerText
                oddD = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(2).innerText
                oddA = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(3).innerText

                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("C" & i) = oddH
                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("D" & i) = oddD
                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("E" & i) = oddA

                Set IE(j + 1) = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                linkbtts = URL & "#bts;2"
                IE(j + 1).Visible = False
                IE(j + 1).Navigate linkbtts

                Do While IE(j + 1).Busy Or IE(j + 1).ReadyState <> 4
                    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                Loop

                Set doc = IE(j + 1).Document

                oddBTTS = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(1).innerText
                oddNBTTS = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(2).innerText

                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("G" & i) = oddBTTS
                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("H" & i) = oddNBTTS
                IE(j + 1).Quit

                Set IE(j + 2) = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                linkover = URL & "#over-under;2;2.50;0"
                IE(j + 2).Visible = False
                IE(j + 2).Navigate linkover

                Do While IE(j + 2).Busy Or IE(j + 2).ReadyState <> 4
                    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                Loop

                Set doc = IE(j + 2).Document

                oddover = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(2).innerText
                oddunder = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(3).innerText

                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("J" & i) = oddover
                Worksheets("Plan1").Range("K" & i) = oddunder
                IE(j + 2).Quit
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next k
        IE(j).Quit
        j = j + 1
    Next jogo
End Sub
```

It showed me 300 games, but then stop and show the error 70 in vba.

Comment: If u resume the code after the error , it works right ?

Comment: Probably the site doesnt like you throwing request at it that much. You might want to put in a delay after each request to the site.

Comment: How i resume the code after the error ? i'm new in vba. After show me the error i simply click in Ok and code stopped running.

Comment: If i put more delay on code instead of 40 minutes to show me all results , the result appears after 1hour or more

Comment: Yes, it takes longer, but that's probably the explicit intended purpose. It sounds like they're kicking you off the site when you send too many request too fast, so the only fix is to not send as many requests as quickly (or see if they let you pay them to get more results or something)

Comment: And how i delay after each request ? Thank you

Comment: You could just throw in another `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)` at the end of the loop, and bump up the number of seconds as needed

Comment: I put 15  "Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)" at the end of the loop and still show me error 70 :(